# No Vibrate Only want Sound in Pushnotification (ios)?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I know the ways for,

1.how to playing sound and vibrating(both) while push notification comes from server to iPhone device

2.Only playing vibrate with no sound.

but I did not find any way to "play only sound and stop vibrating when new push notification comes" on device.
Please suggest me both way.

1) iPhone mode in vibrate.

2) iPhone mode in General.

My Xcode is version 7.2.

I set this dictionary in APN Tester than get sound and vibrate=>

```
{"aps":{"alert":"Hello from APNs Tester.","badge":"1","sound":"default"}}
```

But, I want only sound no vibrate.
I think this question is duplicate . but I can't get proper solution.

Thankx in advance.

Comment: Whomever voted to close this right off the bat is just lazy. This is a valid question with a specific answer. That said, I don't know much about push notifications, good luck!

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw no idea ?

Comment: @rameshbhuja vibrate functionality is user's device setting volume no any parameter in APN payload

Comment: @kirtimali but via webservice PHP side can not set any parameter ?

Comment: @rameshbhuja yes no need to set parameter

Comment: @kirtimali than how to set no vibrate and only play sound ? give some dictionary for set...

Comment: @rameshbhuja i think i cant disable vibrate using programatically

Comment: @kirtimali means when we get notification than compulsory get vibrate rght ?